# How to control div layers (avoid floating over another div)

Tags: html, css

I have added a bottom-fixed bar into my website, but I have a problem, some button in another part of my script, is printing over my bottom-fixed bar, so it looks bad...

How do I control the level of every floating div in my web, to push that button down my bottom-fixed bar?

I've recorded a video to explain what is happening: https://www.loom.com/share/624fc10414cb46859b8a3cf666e0e0a3

Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of the issue, you need to share the relevant code (You can [edit] the post and include it)

Comment: you should use [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: add `z-index: 999;` to your `fixed` rule

Comment: Try `z-index: 999;` on the footer bar

Comment: Great! I will try it :D

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the Z-index of the button is higher than the z-index of your bottom bar. You will want to make sure the bottom bar has the highest z-index if you want it to remain on top of everything.

Try to use z-index as little as possible as it is very easy to fall into the trap of giving something an index of 999 so it can be on top of something, then a year from now having to give something else the index of 9999.

I hope this helps.